# dpkg --status package_name

Tags: apt, dpkg, emacs

I'm just playing around with Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. I installed emacs, and wanted to double check if it was.

```
~ 1496 $ dpkg --status emacs
dpkg-query: package 'emacs' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
```

And I put the line below

```
~ 1497 $ apt-cache show emacs
Package: emacs
Priority: optional
Section: editors
Installed-Size: 25
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Rob Browning <rlb@defaultvalue.org>
Architecture: all
Source: emacs-defaults
Version: 45.0ubuntu1
Depends: emacs24 | emacs24-lucid | emacs24-nox
Filename: pool/main/e/emacs-defaults/emacs_45.0ubuntu1_all.deb
Size: 1624
MD5sum: 2648ac76d7058d4a722ae304e474aa06
SHA1: 6667aaf3b043b44f10271b943dbb9dbb9620dbf2
SHA256: cb9185c543841971a754ebf8c6a35396c865171532b407dce5b5447c41cfa232
Description-en: GNU Emacs editor (metapackage)
 GNU Emacs is the extensible self-documenting text editor.
 This is a metapackage that will always depend on the latest
 recommended Emacs release.
Description-md5: 21fb7da111336097a2378959f6d6e6a8
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
Supported: 5y
```

Now it's seemed to be installed, but I'm still confused WHY the first command shows "emacs is not installed ....".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the proper is to request `emacs24`:

```
dpkg --status emacs24
```

It might due to the `emacs` being a transitional package for `emacs23` and you have `emacs24` installed.